What are all file metadata available to the linux file system that are always available vs optional?
Context: I know that some programs figure out whether they're being run inside a terminal by running the standard C function isatty(STDOUT_FILENO), or isatty(STDIN_FILENO).
I believe also that they can figure out whether the file is a symbolic link or not.
I would like to know what other information programs have access to regarding their input and output files, and to what extent it is possible to hide this information from them.
For example:

Regarding isatty, is it possible to hide this information from a program, by removing the information from the file identifier (without creating a new file)?

Can programs access the file's location in the directory tree?


Question: In general, which file meta-data is available by default? And which of those can be configured to be removed/hidden from a program when configured as their stdin/stdout?

See stat(2), ioctl(2) and (to a lesser extent) fcntl(2) for some of the information that a process can get (and how it gets it).

What's the use case? You could do something like cat | cmd-that-tests-stdin-for-tty, or cmd-that-tests-stdout-for-tty | cat or combine both, to mask the particular fd that you're interested in. Note that TTY and symlink information come from different places - for TTYs, the usual check is to actually perform a TTY operation, lstat(2) for links. Even if you masked the libc wrappers for standard system calls, a command could use the system calls directly, or maybe test the behaviour itself (e.g., lseek(2)) to determine what the file is.

If you have an open fd, it's not a symlink, since symlinks can't be opened. And there's no way to find out what name was used to open the file, symlinks or not.

@muru, I don't have a use case per se, I am more trying to just understand the Linux file system, what metadata there is and which of those are necessarily available, vs optional

The TTY information is definitely not part of the filesystem
